# Taylor Couette Bernoullis

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, viscosity

Has anyone studied a Taylor-Couette flow in the presence of a varying diameter pipe. Is there any research that i can be pointed to to understand how the pressure differences develop in a purely momentum flow (in the absence of a streamwise pressure gradient) ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are the results of numerical simulation shown in the pictures? What software did you use?

Comment: Hi @AlexTrounev these are from a simulation in Autodesk CFD ?

Comment: Do you need to calculate the distribution of $\nabla p$ in this flow?

Comment: Hi @AlexTrounev   Yes that would be good, At present if we took out the radial acceleration pressure variance across the streamline (and the outer wall velocity being equal to flow speed) then it looks to be plain old Bernoullis. That's what i am trying to confirm so an explanation of why the pressure gradients develop would be great .

Comment: Obviously, a viscous flow model is used. The Reynolds number is not specified, apparently this is a laminar flow. We can calculate the Bernoulli integral for this flow.

Answer (score 0):

I calculated a similar flow in [the numerical model](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064) using Mathematica 11.3. The model uses the Navier-Stokes equations for a flat laminar non-compressible flow, finite element method and the method of the false transient. The outer cylinder rotates, the inner one is fixed, Reynolds number $Re=100$. In fig. shows the distribution of the square of velocity $u^2+v^2$, pressure and analogue of the Bernoulli integral $\frac {1}{2}\rho (u^2+v^2)+p$. The pressure difference arises in the process of establishing the solution of a system of equations. The physical reason for the pressure difference is obvious - this is a change in the cross section of the gap. 
[image: fig1]